# What verb is in 覚­えてみたい?

Tags: grammar, words

I found this YouTube comment:

きゃりーぱみゅぱみゅとっても可愛い〜(*ﾉ∀ﾉ)ダンスとか覚­えてみたいと思いまーすww﻿

I'm not sure how to parse 覚­えてみたい. The context seems to make it have nothing to do with 覚る, and in any case the え 送り仮名 doesn't make a bit of sense with さとる.  Is this a typo or some word not in my dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure 覚{おぼ}える isn't in your dictionary? (Am I misunderstanding the question?)

Comment: *facepalm* Why did I not get that it is that word...I guess I need to brush up on kanji readings again. Apparently Google Translate's rōmaji converter is confused too, and thinks 覚 is "satoru".

Comment: @EricDong Interesting point about the 覚{さと}る reading, though :)

Comment: @snailboat @summea For me, `rikaikun` also didn't recognize おぼえる in this particular line of text, though for those in the answers it worked well. Seems like some software fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the given sentence, it sounds like someone is talking about how he/she is wanting to learn (or memorize) the dance moves and choreography of a song by the singer that goes by the name "[Kyary Pamyu Pamyu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyary_Pamyu_Pamyu)".

In this case,「みたい」is actually a form of the verb「みる」which can mean "to try".  When 「みる」is attached to a verb, it simply means: "**to try**" + ***verb***.  So when another form of「みる」is attached to a verb, the meaning will still have something to do with the idea of "to try".

Here is a breakdown of where 覚{おぼ}えてみたい comes from, in this case:

> 覚{おぼ}える　＝ to learn, to memorize
>
> 覚{おぼ}えてみる　＝　[I] will try to learn *(or memorize)*
>
> 覚{おぼ}えてみたい　＝ [I] want to try to learn *(or memorize)*

Answer (score 2):

`覚­えてみたい` = て-form of 覚える + みたい

I guess maybe I'm misunderstanding something about the question too.